# Angular Error cli command Error: You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I have an error when I executed any command with Angular CLI

I tried  the solution by uninstalling and Install it again by executing the below commands

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli 
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

but still i have same issue the issue is
Error: You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands.

Comment: Which ng command did you try out?

Comment: Any command i did i have same issue i tried 
ng version

Comment: Which shell / terminal are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I used `ng version` without `--` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

for linux

1. `Sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update -y`
2. Check node -v
   if this error occur command 'node' node found
   Then
   a.) `sudo apt install nodejs`
3. Check npm -v
   if this error occur command 'npm' node found
   Then
   a.) `sudo apt install npm -y`
4. `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`
5. `ng -v` or `ng v` or `ng --version`

for Window

1. Install Node/npm on your machine.
   Download And Install From this Link : https://nodejs.org/en/download/
   and Check node version by
   `node -v` or node `--version`
   and npm version by `npm -v`
2. Use and install Angular CLI globally.

   npm install -g @angular/cli
3. check the angular install or not by this cmd
   `ng -v` or `ng v` or `ng --version`

Comment: i dont think there a relavance to your anwer,

Answer (score 0):

for me,it works with

use

```
ng version | ng v
```

instead of

```
ng --version | ng --v
```